# Encadeamentos simultâneos (processamento paralelo) em R e gravação serializada no SQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, web-scraping

Olá, pessoal.
Estou tentando desenvolver um código que possibilite fazer um processamento paralelo de tratamento (parser) de arquivos HTML usando a Linguagem R e, consecutivamente, grave os dados extraídos do HTML no Banco de Dados do SQLite de forma serializada.

Para realizar o processamento paralelo, estou usando o pacote `furrr` (esse pacote é similar ao `purrr`, com foco em programação funcional, contudo, a sua vantagem é que ele permite a execução em paralelo (multi-thread) do script.
Já para fazer a conexão com o SQLite e enviar as querys, estou utilizando, respectivamente, o `RSQLite`e o `DBI`.

No código abaixo, a execução ocorre perfeitamente se coloco a função `plan(sequential)` que estabelece uma execução serializada (no meu caso real, promoveria o tratamento dos arquivos HTML e a gravação no SQLite de forma serializada). Mas quando habilito o  `plan(multiprocess)`o script só executa cerca de 25% das gravações e retorna um erro:
`Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params) : database is locked In addition: Warning message:` . Aparentemente, isso indica, ao meu ver, que algum processo (thread) deu erro após encontrar o SQLite bloqueado por outro processo (thread) em execução.

Na documentação do `furrr`os "plan" podem ser configurados da seguinte forma:
`# You set a "plan" for how the code should run. The easiest is 'multiprocess' # On Mac this picks plan(multicore) and on Windows this picks plan(multisession)` ([link](https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr))

O DESAFIO: A minha ideia é que o tratamento dos arquivos HTML fosse realizado em paralelo e as gravações fossem feitas serializadas no SQLite, já que ele não permite gravações simultâneas. Creio que isso gerará ganhos de performance, sobretudo quando houver a necessidade de realizar tratamento (parser) de dados em HTML mais complexos que demoram de ser concluídas.

Alguns caminhos possíveis a ser pensado:

1) É preciso realizar alguma configuração nos parâmetros do `RSQLite::SQLite()`, para solucionar o problema?

2) É necessário utilizar alguma função para tratamento de erro como a `purrr::safely` durante a execução da função `DBI::dbExecute` para que ela fique tentando executar a query no SQLite até conseguir? Ou `purrr::safely` teria que ser usado durante a conexão do SQLite na função `drive_sqlite()`?

3) Há alguma função do pacote `DBI`que ajude a resolver esse problema?

4) Alguma tipo de cache no SQLite para que ele armazene as query recedidas do R e as execute de forma serializada? ([link](https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html))

Já fiz várias tentativas e percorri caminhos diferentes... mas sem sucesso até agora. Alguns dos artigos que já consultei na internet ([link1](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325683/can-i-read-and-write-to-a-sqlite-database-concurrently-from-multiple-connections), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026884/multiple-simultaneous-threads-using-sqlite-in-r), [link4](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html)) .

```
library(furrr)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

drive_sqlite <- function(){ DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "bd_teste.db") }

DBI::dbExecute(drive_sqlite(),"CREATE TABLE tabela_teste (coluna1  TEXT NOT NULL,
                                                          coluna2  TEXT NOT NULL,
                                                          coluna3  TEXT NOT NULL,
                                                          coluna4  TEXT NOT NULL);")

tabela_dados <- tibble::tibble(coluna1 = c(1:3000),
                               coluna2 = c(1:3000),
                               coluna3 = c(1:3000),
                               coluna4 = c(1:3000))

funcao <- function(coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna4) { 

            DBI::dbExecute(drive_sqlite(), "INSERT INTO tabela_teste VALUES(:coluna1,
                                                                            :coluna2,
                                                                            :coluna3,
                                                                            :coluna4);",
                                         params = list(coluna1 = as.character(coluna1),
                                                       coluna2 = as.character(coluna2),
                                                       coluna3 = as.character(coluna3),
                                                       coluna4 = as.character(coluna4)))

            DBI::dbDisconnect(drive_sqlite())

}

#plan(sequential)

plan(multiprocess)

#plan(multisession)

furrr::future_pmap(tabela_dados, funcao, .progress = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Meu caro @GeorgeSantiago seu problema é insolúvel, infelizmente. Isso se deve a implementação do SQLite. O SQLite não é um sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados que permita que os múltiplos processos escrevam ao mesmo tempo. Veja que o seu erro

```
Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params) : database is locked In
```

diz exatamente isso, isto é, **database is locked**. Só para te confirmar o que eu estou falando veja uma das [perguntas](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html) da FAQ do SQLite:

**(5) Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same application access a single database file at the same time?**

Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time. Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But **only one process** can be **making changes to the database at any moment** in time

ou traduzindo: somente um processo por vez consegue alterar a base de dados.

**QUAL É A SOLUÇÃO ENTÃO?**

Eu não testei o seu script mas **com certeza** se você utilizar um sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados mais robusto, feito para ser usado em produção com múltiplos processos, você vai conseguir fácil fazer o que você quer sem bugs. Você pode usar o [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/), o [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/), o [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) e etc. O meu preferido é o Postgres disparado, o que sugiro para você utilizar.

Comment: Olá, Flavio. Obrigado por responder. Contudo, cheguei a uma solução razoável. Coloquei um loop While e usei a função purrr::safely . Com isso, consegui fazer o que pretendia. No caso, quando um nó em paralelo tenta escrever no SQLite enquanto outro nó está escrevendo... o loop While junto com a função purrr::safely fica tentando até que o SQLite seja liberado... Foi um arranjo que fiz para não interromper o processo de execução dos nós com erros.

Comment: Legal, mas veja que de fato você continua com o mesmo problema. No fim das contas o que você fez foi evitar as "colisões" fazendo o script repetir a tentativa de escrita com o safely. Eu sugeriria você aceitar a resposta pois essa é uma confusão comum no uso do SQLite. Veja que o problema não é do seu script, mas o fato de você tentar utilizar um recurso que não existe no SQLite e que é amplamente disponível nos outros programas similares.

Comment: Outro ponto que eu queria salientar é que o remendo com o safely reduz bastante o desempenho da gravação. Apesar de seu processamento ser paralelo a gravação acaba sendo um gargalo tal que nem adianta os processos trabalharem em paralelo pois não conseguem finalizar o processo pois tem de esperar o outro terminar de gravar. E a solução na verdade é bem simples: basta usar um Postgres da vida que tem esse recurso ;-)